# Get list of socket hosts waiting on network

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcpclient

I have multiple TCP Socket servers waiting for connection (one per machine).  On another machine is a client which connects to these servers in order to perform some configuration.

Is there a way for me to see which hosts are on the network waiting for connection (preferably without knowing their IPs).  Is there some way for the host to 'announce' that it is there and waiting for a connection?

All clients/hosts are on the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Each server could certainly broadcast/multicast its listening info to the subnet at regular intervals.  But that is a lot of redundant traffic.

An alternative is to have the client broadcast a request to the subnet that the servers all listen for, and then they can reply directly to the client with their listening info.

Otherwise, the client could just calculate the available IPs for the subnet and then attempt a connection to each IP/port to see which ones succeed or fail (typical port scanning scenario).

Comment: I agree on the redundant traffic piece.  I like the idea of the client calling out to say 'who is there' and the servers responding.  I'm not sure how to go about that.  I wonder if I should update my question, or post a new one.  I was worried about attempting connection to all IPs in case the network sees that as suspicious traffic or something like that.

Comment: Simply have all of the servers open a UDP listening socket on the same port, and then the client can create a UDP socket and send a packet to the subnet's broadcast IP on that port. If a server receives the packet, it will have the client's UDP info to send back a reply containing its TCP info where the client can then connect to